Can someone please edit the EFT tag?
Please can someone with the right privileges, edit the eft tag to Emotion-Focused-Therapy in order to prevent ambiguity with Emotional Freedom Technique developed by Gary Craig?
The tag was created today by the OP of Where to find STORIES about successes with Attachment Disorders and I have created a meta description for it, but would not wish for the tag to be misused or misunderstood by accident, where tag information does not come up in the StackExchange mobile app which is no longer being worked on.

I handled the question by removing the rft flag and replacing it with the emotion-focused-therapy tag. I had to disembark my train and the internet connection was cut short, so I failed to follow up with an answer to your post here :)
Would you like to generate a tag for Emotional Freedom Technique developed by Gary Craig as well? Is it perhaps worth a question and answer from your side to generate the new tag in a relevant question?

I was just thinking that when I raised this. I will do that when I have a chance to put it together

I was just going to post a question and answer, and the system highlighted there was a duplicate which I forgot about. So I added the tag to to that one

You make a good point.
Seemingly somebody already got around to changing it.
For posterity: done!
